# Is Bhagavad-Gita an Upanishad according to the scriptures?

Tags: scripture, bhagavad-gita, smriti, itihasa

Bhagavad-Gita is simultaneously words of God, mentioned as an Upanishad, the 'Smriti-prasthana' and a part of the 'Itihasa-purana'.

The scriptures mention a hierarchy as Vedas and Upanishads > Smritis> Itihasa and Puranas.

**Any Upanishad is a part of the Vedas, but Gita is NOT a part of any Veda.
A smriti is a list of Do's and Don'ts but Gita is not such a Rule Book.**

What us the exact position of Gita AS PER THE SCRIPTURES?

**I am not interested in the personal opinions as discussed in** [Is Bhagavad Gita text Shruti or Smriti?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8959/is-bhagavad-gita-text-shruti-or-smriti)

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I dont think this question should be marked as duplicate. The "original" question does not have a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @LazyLubber We mark questions based on what is asked in the question. The original asks what is Bhagavad Gita a Shriti or Smriti. Satisfactory answers will come in future. Satisfaction is also subjective. It already have good answers not satisfactory if you ask me. Because one of the answers cites Adi Shankara.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma If you look at the answer, it does not really quote Adi Shankara. It merely says Adi Shankara said so and so. Moreover, Adi Shankara is not the only vedAntin. Bhaskara, for instance, treats Bhagavad Gita as almost Sruti. We will miss all these details if we are in a hurry to close questions. And I would disagree with you on one point. If the OP is not satisfied with the answer to a question, he must be allowed to raise it again without incurring the risk of being branded as a duplicate question.

Comment: @LazyLubber If the question is not the same, one can edit the question. Asking the same question again and again is not the way. We must have to face the same question a hundred times because of the reason "Answers are not satisfactory". Avoiding repetition is key point here. Otherwise, oeveryone would post same questions again and again. That would lead to bad situations like getting unnecessary reputation and privileges. The answer says Adi Shankara used that in Gita. What else to do you need. Shankara says "iti smaryate" for multipple shlokas. Ask the answerer the cite the commentary.

Comment: @LazyLubber You are absolutely correct.Also, Adi Shankar's writings are never called 'scriptures'!

Comment: @Sarvabhouma As I said, Shankara is not the only vedantin. And I repeat, he has not been quoted. If he has said something in gita bhashya, where did he say it? The exact reference needs to be provided. And as far as I am concerned, this forum is primarily about sharing knowledge of hinduism - not reputation or privileges. I dont believe questions should be closed based on mere technicalities.

Comment: @commonman Unfortunately, people seem to be too eager to close questions here.

Comment: @LazyLubber I am talking about closing questions here not about the correctness of the answers. We may have difference in opinions in what is right or wrong. See [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates). We are not a forum. Unfortunately, people do not spare a single minute to look whether their questions are asked already. Many users here post repeated questions and just add notes to avoid closure and earn rep. @@Commonman, The other question doesn't ask for personal opinions at all. Asking for opinions means it will be closed.

Comment: @LazyLubber Some people here are always busy to edit questions or mark them as duplicates.Either they do not have the sense to understand what makes a question different, or have been authorized or empowered to act like this or want to get their presence felt by doing these when they can't ask any question or answer any.We have to bear:)

Comment: Whether you are interested or not, a duplicate question is duplicate. And I hope you are aware that we don't accept opinions as answer, so that's not the reason to keep this question open.

Comment: @LazyLubber if an old question don't have satisfactory answer then that doesn't mean this 
new one is not duplicate. Users are most welcome to write answers for the other post, no problem in that.

Comment: @KrishnaShweta ' And I hope you are aware that we don't accept opinions as answer' --so the accepted answer was based on scriptural source? Fine.Then I do not know what the scriptures are, as I read the accepted answer.It is duplicate only if the earlier question was at all concerned about scriptural reference.If yes, then thats beyond my perception.