# What is the origin of bhagavad gita?

Tags: mahabharata

Who exactly wrote down the gita, and who exactly was the author of it. Are there any historical records about when it first appeared, was it narrated at first, if so was the whole epic of mahabarata narrated, how did they remember all of it.

Comment: Are you looking for origin of Mahabharata or Gita? Please clarify.

Comment: Both, are they not one scripture?

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8959/647

Comment: Yea but I don't really care about that in this question, I simply want to consider hystorical facts here

Comment: Since this site is mainly for religion, historical facts are not of much importance here. In that, what's stated in BG is more important than who actually wrote it. One could write an answer to your question here but it would be downvoted & even deleted. Try reading C. V. Vaidya's opinion on this [here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.11833/page/n663/mode/2up), also V. R. Narla's [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Cy1xLqlixr8C&lpg=PA4&dq=The%20Truth%20About%20the%20Gita%3A%20A%20Closer%20Look%20at%20Hindu%20Scripture&pg=PA103#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: You can also ask the same question on History SE where you may get better answers than here.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense

Comment: Why would you delete something that is an integral part of the very point of this site.

Comment: Of course hystorical facts matter, they bring another perspective on the essence and content, you cannot just remove it from the conversation

Comment: While I agree with you, that's just how the site currently operates. You can ask about it on [Hinduism Meta SE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com). The main issue here is that traditional views on the authorship of BG are different from historical. E.g., [a question about the Ganges river](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/46093/historically-when-and-why-did-ganga-become-a-holy-river-is-it-after-sarasvat) has been migrated from here to History.SE because users here started posting answers based on mythology. I suspect your question here will suffer the same fate.

Comment: @Puppetmaster there are no historical facts as it is not proven that the historical events actually took place. This is mythology not history.