# who wrote Bhagavad Gita/Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavad-gita

If we google this question we get **Sage Vyasa** as answer and that what I have learned growing up. But **Shri Krishna** gave this knowledge to **Arjuna** only, and there so on one else there who was writing that down. **Sanjay** was only relaying the information to **Dritharashtra**. **Sage Vyasa** was not anywhere near **Kurukshetra** then how would he knew exact words of **Lord Krishna** and wrote that down?

Like in **Ramayana**, **Sage Valmiki** had boon of seeing everything that was going to happen and he wrote it down and this was also mentioned in Ramayana.

Also when was it written, after it all happened or before (like in Ramayana)?

Comment: Related or Duplicate of  
 https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/39970/what-is-the-origin-of-bhagavad-gita

Comment: Vyasa also got the boon. Not just seeing the incidents. They wil l experience the events. Seeing or watching is a part of experience. They also experience the thoughts of the people.

Comment: Ganesh wrote the Gita and Vyasa used his supernatural foresight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vyasa did not need to be anywhere near Kurukshetra to know what was going on. Because Sanjaya who could hear the discourse of Lord Krishna and Arjuna could do so due to the boon given to him by Vyasa himself (as per *vyasa prasadata srutavan*... Gita verse). So if Vyasa could grant others boon to hear the distant events, can't he himself know them!

Regarding the composition of Mahabharata, it happened in many stages as the totality of Mahabharata was not composed right away. However, it should be known that the Veda, Purana, Itihasa etc. are only made available to this world at certain point, they are eternally there and originate from the breath of the Lord at the time of creation (reference for it can be found in many scriptures). The Mahabharata was made available to the general public many years after the events of Mahabharata war when Janmenjaya, the great grand son of Arjuna, performed the snake sacrifice. During the sacrifice a disciple of Vyasa named Vaisampayana narrated it to the audience gathered there. More details can be found in the first chapter of Mahabharata.