# Why Bhagvad Geeta is classified as Smriti and not Shruti? Even though it was told directly by Brahman in the form of Shri Krishna?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, smriti, pramana, shruti

In the Bhagvad Geeta, the Parabrahman had proved his Authenticity, Authority and the divine knowledge. It is the only book so far where god refers himself with "I".

So, why should it be classified as Smriti and not Shruti?

This is important because Shrutis have more weight as Pramana (Proof) than Smritis.

Comment: Does this answer your question [Is Bhagwat Gita text Shruti or Smriti?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8959/647) ?

Comment: @thelittlenaruto that question is asking whether Bhagvad Gita is Smriti or Shruti. I am rather proposing its a Shruti and would like to see challenging thoughts.

Comment: Gita is part of Mahabharata which was authored by Ved Vyasa .. Vedas in contrast do not have authors .. this is a difference you can think about.  In various Puranas we have many other Gitas too (Iswara Gita etc.) where too Gods speak .. that does not make those Gitas or Puranas Sruti.

Comment: @RaxitSoni Just go through the answers, I think your question was already answered in one of them. Also what Rickross said is right.