# Is there any mention of geeta before sankara bhashya?

Tags: scripture, history, bhagavad-gita, vedanta, adi-shankaracharya

Gita is believed to be a chief text of vedanta.

It is one of the three fundamental texts of vedanta.

It is said that the first mention and commentary of gita is done by sankara which is about 1000 years ago.

Is there any text prior to sankara bhashya which mention about it ?

Any scholars prior to sankara who quoted it ?

Comment: But teachings of Geeta are not VedAntic directly. Lord Krishna himself said in Geeta - the knowledge is more secret than VedAnta. Although all VedAnta systems include BG as their part but the original VedAnt which was existing during Krishna's time obviously didn't have Krishna's teachings in any form. I think earlier VedAnta means only Upanishad & Brahmasutras ( not Brahmasutras which are present today.)

Comment: Mahabharata (as present in sacred-text) has Gita as part of Bhishma Parva.

Comment: @iammilind same.mbh of sacred text says that santi parva is an interpolation. Anyway question is why its not quoted by anyone before him whether or.not its part of mbh. If indeed so.much important

Comment: "If no
How come there is no mention of such an important text (vedanta) prior to sankara" would be opinion based only.

Comment: @Pandya If its part of prasthana trayi then it should be quoted like the.upanishad

Comment: @RakeshJoshi For Prasthanatrayi, see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3631/277

Comment: @Pandya i am already familiar about it. That is why this question on one of the prasthana trayi. Of the so called most popular hindu philosophy :)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, hence this is a comment. If there was any commentary before Sri Sankara, then it was probably lost in time. Sri Sankara's time  is disputed and there are three different periods suggested. So the exact time when Sri Sankara Bhashyam was composed is the first unknown. So any work(s) done prior to that period, is also unknown at least for now.

Answer (score 8):

## Is there any text prior to sankara bhashya which mention about it?

Yes ,[**Shandilya Bhakti Sutras**](https://archive.org/stream/ShandilyaBhaktiSutra/shandilya_bhakti_sutras#page/n179/mode/2up) mentions Shreemad Bhagvat Gita . Rishi  Shandilya is said to be the author of   Shandilya Bhakti Sutras during the time period of the  Mahabharata  (300 BCE. ). However the exact  date of the text is a point of debate among  scholars. Here is Shandilya Bhakti Sutra no. 83.

> सैकान्तभावो गीतार्थप्रत्यभिग्य्नाज्ञानात् || 83||
>
> Sa Ekanta Bhava Gitartha Prati abhijnanat
>
> One who understood the essence knows that true purport of the Gita is
>   exclusive and unalloyed devotion to Godhead.

This sutra is pointing towards the Bhagavad Gita Shlokas  6. 30 , 9.22  ,9.34  , 11.55 ,12.6 etc.

---

We can download Narada and Shandilya Bhakti Sutras both in [**Sanskrit-Hindi**](https://archive.org/stream/NaradAurShandilyaBhaktiSutra/Narad%20aur%20Shandilya%20Bhakti%20Sutra#page/n13/mode/2up) here.

Comment: Then who wrote this ? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shandilya_Upanishad

Comment: Can you give word to word translation? Prtyabhijna is translated to what here? . Also, are you sure he is talking about Bhagwat Geeta only?