# First refrence to the Prasthanatrayi?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, vedanta, upanishads, brahma-sutras, prasthanatrayi

What is the first reference to the Prasthanatrayi and are these three like the "Bible" or one book of Vedanta?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/33523/4732

Comment: It appears that this concept is a man made addition not found in any scriptures.

Comment: @Rickross yes, but did any old scholar refer to it?

Comment: @Rickross btw did you get my comment regarding the discussion?

Comment: Yes I got it and you can continue posting your comments in that chat room